# What is an elegant way to make logger to always prepend the test method name on all logs generated during its execution?

Tags: kotlin, log4j, testng

Consider the following setup below:

```
@Test
class MyTest {

    @Test
    fun testX(sessionId: String) {
        methodName = object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
        LOGGER.info("Test {}: Doing", methodName)
        helper(methodName)
        LOGGER.info("Test {}: Done", methodName)
    }

    fun helper(methodName: String) {
        LOGGER.info("Test {}: Helping", methodName)
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to configure the logger to always prepend the test name (like above) to all loggings done within the scope of the test, s,t. I don't have to pass the method name everywhere.

One option I can think of I can think of is MDC (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html). However, I can see it's not gonna work well in TestNG since the same class instance is shared between test cases (unlike JUnit).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using TestNG listeners for that.

Here is a small example. Create a class implementing `ITestListener`:

```
class MyListener: ITestListener {
    private val logger: Logger = getLogger(MyListener::class.java)

    override fun onTestStart(result: ITestResult?) {
        logger.info("Test {}: doing", result?.name)
    }
}
```

Then, register it with this annotation:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners
import org.testng.annotations.Test

@Listeners(MyListener::class)
class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun testX() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    fun testY() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    fun testZ() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So running your tests you should get something like this:

```
13:38:57.008 [Test worker] INFO MyListener - Test testX: doing
13:38:57.015 [Test worker] INFO MyListener - Test testY: doing
13:38:57.016 [Test worker] INFO MyListener - Test testZ: doing
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not addressing my issue.. I am interested to have the test name in every log line emitted within the scope of the test execution. In addition, the solution you mentioned above is achievable with @BeforeMethod

Comment: @user1836155, sure it is achievable but @BeforeMethod is not intended for such usage. If you really need to append method name using Log4j only, you can adjust *conversion pattern* to include method name using `M` placeholder. This approach is not recommended due to performance concerns.
See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html for details

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, I doubt %M works for the case where helper() is called.